# Differentiator output

Tags: capacitor

[image]

So I’ve wrapped my head around Differentiator. I understand how a small R will produce allow Vc to be ~Vin, for DC. And adding a load will mean that the current across R (not labeled but there) will decrease, and increase Vc. So there is: an output proportional to the rate of change of input.

The output proportional to the rate of change of input is dVc/dt in I = CdVc/dt. Here the proportion is times C. Attaching a load, it would be a fraction of I (aCdVc/dt) and then the voltage across it would be Rload * aCdVc/dt. Correct? And now, I imagine there are mA to uA and a resistor of 100k to get some voltage drop. Thinking quickly to get help, I’d love to know the uses of an output proportional to the rate of change of input and if this is how that output is used (i.e. Rload * a*CdVc/dt).

Kind of a tangent: a while ago I considered using an integrator to produce an LED that glows brighter.

Comment: What you have drawn is a high pass filter.  Simply, if you are only interested at looking at frequencies above a certain value, you can use this configuration to reject the lower frequencies.

Comment: This question is too broad. It's like asking "what are some ways the output of an amplifier can be used?"

Comment: Did you notice you grounded 2 of the 3 phase lines in your paper?  ;) ;) ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Wrap your neurons around these scope traces](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2054%205%2050%0Av%20176%2096%20176%2032%200%202%2080%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20176%20224%20336%20224%200%202000%0Ac%20336%2032%20336%2096%200%200.000009999999999999999%204.999999999627652%0Aw%20176%2096%20336%2096%200%0Av%20176%20192%20176%20128%200%202%2080%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20176%2032%20336%2032%200%2020%0Aw%20176%20192%20336%20192%200%0Ac%20336%20128%20336%20192%200%200.00001%204.132087509789898%0Av%20176%20288%20176%20224%200%202%2080%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20176%20288%20336%20288%200%0Ac%20336%20224%20336%20288%200%200.000009999999999999999%200.45782833199854966%0Ar%20176%20128%20336%20128%200%20200%0A403%20384%2064%20512%20112%200%202_64_0_4097_1.25_0.8_0_2_2_3%0A403%20384%2032%20512%2064%200%202_64_0_4098_5_0.8_0_2_2_3%0A403%20384%20160%20512%20208%200%207_64_0_4097_5_0.1_0_2_7_3%0A403%20384%20128%20512%20160%200%207_64_0_4098_5_0.1_0_2_7_3%0A403%20384%20256%20512%20288%200%2010_64_0_4097_5_0.003125_0_2_10_3%0A403%20384%20224%20512%20256%200%2010_64_0_4098_1.25_0.003125_0_2_10_3%0A).  This should clear it up.

Then change all the generator properties to SIN.

Try a sawtooth.

Then drag and stretch the endpoints to make it an integrator but remember 5mm W. 
[image]

Finally.... LEDs are around 12 #Ohms @ 3.1V 20mA and not 3.1V/0.02A = 165 ohms avg when it comes to making a smooth turn on near full current.  That's# the Ri incremental impedance# of the zener-like diode response.

Comment: +/- 5V input in case you didn't guess correctly

Comment: Thanks man. What do you mean by 5mm W.

Comment: @T.Stewart So I've thought about this. And I've realized the following thoughts. The capacitor's property I = CdV/dt allow it to be used as a differentiator. The capacitor needs to be connected to ground to allow current to flow. Although with this configuration, any input signal will go to ground. So we add the "current sensing resistor." This current sensing resistor allows the signal to be used by an IC as shown in the OP. A varying resistor, increases the time constant RC. A larger RC, means a longer time to fully charge, the rate of change of voltage is flatter. (continued in next comment

Comment: So we can use this differentiator for a leading edge detector or rising edge detector with a small R. small RC. quick fully charged. large rate of change of voltage across capacitor so the current signal through the capacitor will be a spike. And we want to avoid loading, so the R must be larger than the input impedance. And we can use a buffer at the next stage of the circuit to propagate this ideal condition (right....I think so.) And so my brain sees an abyss, now, thinking about the use of a signal generator by the capacitor that looks like the second and third current graph in your pict.

Comment: 5 mm White LED... If you can understand my scope simulations from 1st principles , review study again, it will all make sense. Don’t stop until it does.  you can add trace voltage, current,power to any part